# Outlook - Shared Mailbox - Quick Steps

Tags: windows, email, outlook, shared

I am wondering if there is a way to use your own Outlook quick steps in emails using a shared Mailbox?

I have seen the way of using MFCMAPI to export the Quick Steps as MSG files, but this is not the route we'd like to go down, as this would overwrite the shared mailbox's quick steps, and also every time you add a quick step you'd have to again manually export.

We would like to be able to simply use the main profile's quick steps on the shared mailbox. No overwriting or having to manually import every time a quick step is changed.

Answer (score 0):

For a delegate mailbox, Outlook always shows the quick steps from the primary mailbox. Are you trying to set quick steps for another user?

If [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [quick steps](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoquicksteps.htm) on the store level so that you can manipulate them programmatically.

Comment: This is a company user I'm asking for, I'm in IT Support. I don't think it would be a good idea to "work around limitations imposed by the Outlook Security Patch" haha!

Comment: Redemption is not some kind of a black hat hacking tool, it is a programing library that uses the native Outlook API (Extended MAPI) not subject to the security prompts.